# Colocar maximo de linhas no resumo do wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Olá galera eu gostaria de saber como faço para colocar um limite de 5 linhas no resumo.

`<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Até onde sei por linhas você não conseguiria fazer, porém poderia ser feito por volume de caracteres como segue abaixo:

```
<?php   
    $content = get_the_content('',FALSE,'');    
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);  
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);     
    echo substr($content,0,262); 
?>&hellip;
```

Comment: vlw amigo...consegui